# Free website host for embedding tilemill/mapbox web map

Tags: web-mapping, tilemill, mapbox

I am hoping to design a simple interactive web map using TileMill. I am then planning on uploading that map to Mapbox.com, where I understand I will be given an embed code to put on a website. My question is: will this mapbox map seamlessly embed onto a Wordpress or Wix website? Or should I use a different free website platform? Nota bene: I have little HTML editing experience.

Thanks!

Comment: For Wordpress embedding, have you tried the [MapBox WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mapbox)?

Answer (score 2):

I like Github for hosting static pages. It's free as long as you don't require private repos. The folder and URL structure is a little funky, but it works great and you can use your own domain name.

You can host pages from any repo by using a special branch, but the easiest way is to make a repo called [*username*.github.io.](https://pages.github.com)

Comment: can you explain how you would actually implement a map from mapbox in this? Also, I understand, that this would mean that you host the tiles with mapbox, and then use github pages for just the page with the HTML & JS for the Map.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe The OP asked about embedding a map, so I really didn't think past the iframe example [here](https://www.mapbox.com/foundations/share-your-map/#embed). Are you thinking of something that requires more than javascript and the MapBox API?